# phaser AnimationFrame size isse

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

my atlas pack the frame image size is not equal. so I need to determine the display position by setting the coordinates of the frame image.but phaser AnimationFrame image size needs to be equal.
Otherwise, it cannot be displayed in the correct position.

```
 this.anims.create({
            key: 'snooze',
            frames: [
                { key: 'cat1' },
                { key: 'cat2' },
                { key: 'cat3' },
                { key: 'cat4', duration: 50 }
            ],
            frameRate: 8,
            repeat: -1
        });
```

```
 this.anims.create({
            key: 'snooze',
            frames: [
                { key: 'cat1',px:-100:py:0},
                { key: 'cat2',px:-50,py:-30},
                { key: 'cat3',px:-50,py:-30},
                { key: 'cat4', duration: 50,px:-50,py:-30 }
            ],
            frameRate: 8,
            repeat: -1
        });
```

How to set the relative display position of AnimationFrame image by px like expected code effect or other way

```
 this.anims.create({
            key: 'snooze',
            frames: [
                { key: 'cat1',px:-100:py:0},
                { key: 'cat2',px:-50,py:-30},
                { key: 'cat3',px:-50,py:-30},
                { key: 'cat4', duration: 50,px:-50,py:-30 }
            ],
            frameRate: 8,
            repeat: -1
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, what you are looking for is not possible, *at least not **out-of-the-box***.

My suggestion is to create a ***new json***, with matching frames, or ***creating two distinct json's***

```
//  in preload function/method
this.load.atlas('atlas1', 'image.png', 'first.json');
this.load.atlas('atlas2', 'image.png', 'second.json');
```

Or if you want to create dynamically frame, you could,

1. load the image

   ```
   //  in preload function/method 
   this.load.image('image', 'image.png');
   ```
2. and create a texture and frame ([for details check documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Textures.CanvasTexture.html#drawFrame__anchor))

   ```
   let canvas = this.textures.createCanvas('player', 42 * FRAMES, 68);
   let width = 16;
   let height = 32;
   for(let frameIdx = 0; frameIdx < FRAMES; frameIdx ++){
       canvas.drawFrame('image', null, width * idx, height);
       canvas.add(idx, 0, width * idx, 0, width, height);
   }
   canvas.refresh();
   ```

Or similar, you could checkout this example from the offical website (https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/animation/create-animation-from-canvas-texture)